# Cannot update because of Missing packages (12.04 LTS)

Tags: 12.04, apt, updates, update-manager, cinnamon

I'm not being able to update my Ubuntu 12.04 because of missing packages, how can I solve it?

Here's a link of the error I'm getting every time I want to update:
[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're using cinnamon for your desktop environment (or that you have it installed/ppa is there) but, because the developer stopped using that ppa for 14.04 there is nothing there that apt sees as compatible.

To fix, do this:

1. Open a terminal
2. Type the following:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:gwendal-lebihan-dev/cinnamon-stable

   sudo apt-get update
   ```

And then try again to update.

Comment: First of all, thank you for the quick response. I've typed what you've said and I can't access PPA for that address (my internet connection) works fine: http://i.imgur.com/2xtuoMu.png